# Error Elasticsearch on reindexing - No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, reindex, indexing, elasticsearch

When I launch a full reindex (`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`), I have two errors for these indexes : *"Catalog Search" , "ElasticSuite Category"*

I have the Smile/Elasticsuite module installed on my M2, these are my versions of elasticsearch installed with composer :

- elasticsearch/elasticsearch                       v2.3.2
- smile/elasticsuite                                2.6.2

I already find an answer here : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/804#issuecomment-354806052

The guy say "*string is deprecated and you should be using text or keyword instead.*"

But I don't understand where I can apply these changes, if anyone know something about this problem, please let me know, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE :

Good news, if I changed my `smile/elasticsuite` 2.5.15, the reindexing seems to work.

Bad news, it creates another bug in all category page :

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   /vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-virtual-category/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php
>   on line 153

There are the two lines related with this error :

```
$virtualRule = $category->getVirtualRule();
$data = call_user_func_array([$virtualRule, $callback], [$category]);
```

Somehow, the `$virtualRule` variable is NULL, and the function `call_user_func_array` doesn't like this, I'm opening another ticket, but if someone already saw this thing, feel free to answer, thanks !